# Unfortunately app has stopped when building settings using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings

I tried to make settings for my app using this guide from google [Settings | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).
But whenever I try to open settings it says Unfortunately has stopped.

MainActivity.java

```
...
Intent startSettings;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startSettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
}
public void openSettings() {
    startActivity(startSettings);
}
...
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
...
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Load preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/main_settings_title"
        android:key="pref_key_main_settings">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="pref_key_enable_service"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_enable_service"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_enable_service"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Logcat errors

```
07-09 11:37:24.355  26218-26218/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ilolabs.ctdn/com.ilolabs.ctdn.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: This should be called after super.onCreate.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2072)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This should be called after super.onCreate.
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.requirePreferenceManager(PreferenceFragment.java:318)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:283)
    at com.ilolabs.ctdn.SettingsFragment.onCreate(SettingsFragment.java:14)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5249)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4863)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to read this logcat and search my code for errors, but I couldn't find reason for crash in the code that makes sense to me. I haven't got much experice yet, I'm a newbie. Please point out where did I do wrong? I followed exactly how the google guide from above link explained to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in SettingsFragment's onCreate method. Look at the last "Caused by" line in the exception stacktrace.

Comment: YES! Thank you very much. This solved it :) :) :) I'm sorry I guess that was so dumb error, I guess I still don't understand the function of super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), I will investigate more about it. You gave me the direction

Comment: Wow that's an awesome tip for looking at the "Caused by"! Thank you again. Apparently I have to wait for some time before I can accept this answer as correct. I will mark it within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this -

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Load preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
```